# Adding async message processing to some MVC requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, akka.net

I have a site built in `asp.net mvc 5` and it integrates/communicates with other systems/sites. At some points there is the need to communicate to several of these other systems and we are doing so synchronously now, so the original request would have to wait for all other communications to take place before it can get some response. There is already a failure/recovery mechanism (synchronously as well) so that's not a main concern now.

I would like to add asynchrony to some requests (those talking to other systems) so that when they come in I can say *"OK"* and then asynchronously do all communication/processing and not leave the caller waiting. I have seen `akka.net` and it seems fine for what I intend to do, but maybe is an overkill since it's just a few request I want to "asynchronize". So my question is:

Is there anything simpler than `akka.net` that will let me do what I want?

#### EDIT:

A fire and forget approach is not what I'm after since I also need to see/consult/query what is been processed and what will be processed, cancel some of those *items* to be processed and error recovery (and if possible reporting).

Comment: It sounds like you want a "fire and forget" call, is that right? That is not so easy in asp.net. I don't think akka will save you either, but if you find it to be so I would like to know myself. You could use a separate process like a message queue to make those service calls or [check out this blog on fire and forget in asp.net](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html)

Comment: In that case, you cannot return a response until all operations are complete, even if they execute in an async manner.

Comment: @Crowcoder I have read edited my question and read your linked post. I have used *HangFire* before but it also looks like an overkill for what I need. Thank you very much

Comment: @Crowcoder I can say all OK to the caller before doing any extra processing, in my case all the caller cares is that it's request came through, all the extra processing is on our side, to change stuff in my system only. That's why I need error tolerance